# how to take pairs of lines and concatenate?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, text

I have a file which has the format:

```
instance1 field1
instance1 field2
instance2 field1
instance2 field2
instance3 field1
instance3 field2
...
```

and I want to have a oneliner such that it is converted to:

```
instance1 field1 field2
instance2 field1 field2
instance3 field1 field3
```

etc.

I could write the following type of perl script:

```
while (<STDIN>)
{
 $line = $_;
 $line2 = <STDIN>;
 chomp $line; chomp $line2;
 print "$line $line2\n";
}
```

but I would much rather have a oneliner. any ideas?

Comment: One record per line, or the whole file in one line?

Comment: oh oops it wasn't formatted correctly. let me fix. @Raman

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions utilizing the line number `$.`:

```
perl -lane 'print $. % 2 ? @F[0,1] : " $F[1]\n"' file
```

Or

```
perl -pe '$. % 2 ? chomp : s/\S*//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed and awk:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' file.txt | awk '{print $1, $2, $4}'
```

Comment: Though this is a little touchy with respect to EOFs...`cat file.txt | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' - | awk '{print $1, $2, $4}'` works for me, but `sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' - | awk '{print $1, $2, $4}' < file.txt` does not.

Answer (score 0):

This perl one-liner is a *touch long* but it works.

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{%h}{chomp;($k,$v) = split(/\s/,$_);$h{$k} .= qq( $v)}END{foreach( sort keys %h){print qq($_$h{$_}\n)}}' file
```

**Bonus:** solution allows you to have more than two (2) fields in the future without updating the script.

Answer (score 0):

using gnu sed

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s/ \w*//2' file
```

using awk

```
awk '{printf (NR%2)?$0 FS:$2 RS}' file
```

Comment: **Code Golf:** `awk '$0=(NR%2?$0 FS:$2 RS)' ORS= file`

Answer (score 0):

You might not something this generic, but just in case, the following groups by the first field:

```
perl -lane'
   push @{ $i{ $F[0] } }, $F[1];
   END {
      print join "\t", $_, @{ $i{$_} }
         for sort keys %i;
   }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `paste` and GNU `cut`

```
<file paste -d ' '  - - | cut --complement -f3 -d ' '
instance1 field1 field2
instance2 field1 field2
instance3 field1 field2
```